# storing fixed known data in classes (c++)

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, oop

I have this class to store fixed known data. Each object should have its own unique id in such way that, when the user calls `Belt belt(1)`, an object with the correct values of `name`, `perimeter`, `nOfPoints` is created. Is there any better way to define these other parameters without a switch-case? Should I design this in another way? What are the disadvantages of such implementation?

```cpp
class Belt {
    private:
        int _id;
        std::string _name;
        int _perimeter;
        int _nOfPoints;
    public:
        Belt(int id){
            _id = id;
            switch (id)
            {
            case 1:
                _name = "NEO";
                _perimeter = 100;
                _nOfPoints = 10;
                break;
            case 2:
                _name = "PED";
                _perimeter = 200;
                _nOfPoints = 12;
                break;
            case 3:
                _name = "ADT";
                _perimeter = 400;
                _nOfPoints = 20;
                break;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: Why not create `static const Belt`s with the correct values?

Comment: @Stephen Neweell how so? by declaring static const structs?
what if this Belt class should have methods for data manipulation?

Comment: An alternative to the `std::map` is to make a const array of a structure that contains the ID and the belt object.  This eliminates the need for run-time initialization (the `std::map` requires run-time initialization).  The "table" can be placed into a constant memory section and be accessed directly.

Comment: You could use an array of Belt objects.  If you did that you could create an object with `Belt x = belts[1];` or if you want the array to be a private member of the class and pass an integer into the constructor then https://onlinegdb.com/H1yai4b8v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any better way to define these other parameters without a switch-case?

You could use a private static map to hold your prototypes:

```
class Belt {
private:
    static const std:map<int,Belt> prototypes;
    int _id;
    std::string _name;
    int _perimeter;
    int _nOfPoints;

    Belt(int id, const std::string name, int perimeter, int nOfPoints)
        : _id(id), _name(name), _perimeter(perimeter), _nOfPoints(nOfPoints) {}
public:
    Belt(int id) {   
        _id = id;
        _name = prototypes[_id]._name;  
        _perimeter= prototypes[_id]._perimeter;  
        _nOfPoints= prototypes[_id]._nOfPoints;  

        // Or simpler instead of the lines above:
        // *this = prototypes[id];
    }
};

const std:map<int,Belt> Belt::prototypes = {
      { 1 , Belt(1,"NEO",100,10) }
    , { 2 , Belt(2,"PED",200,12) }
    , { 3 , Belt(3,"ADT",400,20) }
};
```

---

Also you might be interested to have a look at the [*Prototype Design Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype). That's an alternative technique you can use, and gives you better flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only going to have a fixed set of values to deal with, I'd suggest making `static const` instances in `Belt`.  This has the advantage of avoiding any lookup overhead, and dealing with invalid input (e.g., somebody passes `INT_MAX` to your constructor).  For example:

```
class Belt {
    private:
        int _id;
        std::string _name;
        int _perimeter;
        int _nOfPoints;

        Belt(int id, name, perimeter, nOfPoints)
          : _id{id}, _name{std::move(name)}
          , _perimeter{perimeter}, _nOfPoints{nOfPoints} { }

    public:
        static const Belt neo(1, "NEO", 100, 10);
        static const Belt ped(2, "PED", 200, 12);
        // ...
};
```

A user can create a local `Belt` by copying one of the existing objects, and still perform any local manipulations that they need.

```
int main() {
    auto myBelt = Belt::neo;
    myBelt.some_member_function();
}
```